# iOS Collection view flow layout dynamic row height with max height of item in row

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I want to create collection view cells which should have max height of item in row. Each item is having dynamic height. Wanted to stretch cells to maximum row height.

Attached the screenshot for same below:[image: Attached screenshot for current layout]

So i would like to stretch item 1 & item 3 to match item 2 height, and item 6 to match item 4 & 5 height and alignment.

Please suggest the solution, its kind of top and bottom aligned flow together I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can still helpful.

```
    AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout(horizontalAlignment: .justified,
verticalAlignment: .top)
```